# C++ function that take a member function and return a static lambda/std::function to it

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, member

I would like to implement a member function that take a pointer to an other member function and return a static binding. Could be whatever: a `lambda` or a ?  `std::function`.

Since this moment, I made the following intent in C++11 without success:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass{
public:
    auto link( std::function<void(MyClass::*)(int)> func)->std::function<void(int)>
    {
        return [this, func](int i){func(i);};
    }
    auto myFunc(int i)->void { std::cout << "Ok:" << i << std::endl; }

    auto test ()->void
    {
        link(&MyClass::myFunc)(4);
    }
};

auto main()->int
{
    MyClass c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specialization `std::function<T>` is only defined if `T` is a function type. There is no `std::function<T>` where `T` is a pointer to member function type. Anyway, there's no sense in constructing an `std::function` for the argument if you just want to pass in pointers to member functions. You can do so directly like this:

```
auto link(void (MyClass::*func)(int))->std::function<void(int)>
```

A pointer to member function must be invoked using the `.*` or `->*` operator with an expression of appropriate class or pointer to class type (respectively) on the left. Therefore in this case you can write:

```
return [this, func](int i){(this->*func)(i);};
```

Comment: *"there is no std::function<T> that can be directly constructed from a pointer to member function"*, there is `std::function<void(MyClass*,int)>`

Comment: @PiotrS. Whoops, I forgot that C++ actually lets you do that. I'll have to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this using `std::bind` with either pointer to member, or `std::function`, as you wish:

```
auto link_pointer_to_member(void(MyClass::*func)(int))->std::function<void(int)>
{
    return std::bind(func, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}

auto link_function( std::function<void(MyClass*, int)> func)->std::function<void(int)>
{
    return std::bind(func, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on the other answers, you could generalize this for any member function pointer like this:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
auto link( Ret(MyClass::*func)(Args...))->std::function<Ret(Args...)>
{
    return [this, func](Args... args){ return (this->*func)(args...);};
}
```